# javascript is not working with flask applications

Tags: javascript, html, flask, jinja2, staticresource

i have got data from the app.py written in flask. i have logged the data in script section and data was correct but when i use to create an tag or update the src of an existing tag, the tags are being displayed empty.

i am using javascript to give action to the webpage. when i click a button a video present in the static folder will be displayed and played.
my flask method :-

```
@app.route('/get_video_url')
def get_video_url():
    video_path = "static/output.mp4"
    if not os.path.exists(video_path):
        print("not found")
        return jsonify({'video_url': "no"})
    return jsonify({'video_url': "output.mp4"})
```

my file Structure:- [File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NRAs.png)

my javascript:-

```
document.getElementById('playButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/get_video_url');
                const data = await response.json();
                console.log(data)
                const videoUrl = data.video_url;
                console.log(videoUrl)
                // Set the video source
                if (videoUrl === "no") {
                    document.getElementById('myVideo').innerHTML = `<p>video not found</p>`;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('myVideo').src = "/static/output.mp4";
                    document.getElementById('myVideo').style.display = 'block';
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching video URL:', error);
            }
        });
```

what i can see in page source:-  document.getElementById('myVideo').src = "/static/output.mp4";
but my video was blank. The server was sending the responses correctly. but javascript was unable to update the responses.
my terminal:-

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Feb/2024 21:51:42] "GET /static/output.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 206 -
```

Comment: What happens if you visit `/static/output.mp4` from your browser? Does it play the video? Also, you're not using `videoUrl`.

Comment: @BoppreH sir, i can't see the video from the browser when i visit /static/output.mp4, but i can see that in my file structure sir.   sir, i have changed that to document.getElementById('myVideo').src = '/static/output.mp4' later sir. still not working. sir, i badly need help on this.

Comment: -a---l        16-02-2024     12:37          12885 home_builtini.css
-a----        19-02-2024     22:56           3431 myjav.js
-a----        19-02-2024     22:53        9625447 output.mp4
-a---l        16-02-2024     12:01           9298 traffic_image.avif this is my file structure sir @BoppreH

Comment: If you cannot see the video from the browser, then it's not a problem with your javascript. What happens when you visit `static/output.mp4`, do you get any browser errors? What if you save the file, does it save the contents correctly?

Comment: i see an empty video just loading but not displaying anything. i mean it's just black with controls on top. sir, i can't get you. what you mean by save contents correctly? . sir , actually the video was being created by processing frames. when i play it from vs editor it was being played. more over it pass this condition in flask too. that is if not os.path.exists(video_path): . sir, please provide your assistance.

Comment: Can you open `output.mp4` from the OS (not through a browser)?

Comment: @qrsngky sir, when i open the output.mp4 using vscode, it was displaying "An error occured while loading the video, open file using vscode standard text/binary code editor ?". seems like the file i am using in not saved in correct format. i am using opencv to save the video sir. fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')
    writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_filename, fourcc, fps,
                             (frame_width, frame_height)) , my output file is .mp4 format and what fourcc codec should i use ?

Comment: @qrsngky sir, but i can one the output.mp4 using my media player in my system. there was an other video file which was opening in vscode but output.mpr is not opening.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the javascript was working, the problem lies in the video i am trying to render. The video codec was not matched with the browser and video was black and empty. i just replaced fourcc as -1 and problem solved in opencv.